# c# webbrowser cyrillic path to file

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, cyrillic

Good day.
I need to open a pdf file through WebBrowser, the path contains a Cyrillic alphabet.

```
WebBrowser wb1 = new WebBrowser();
wb1.Navigate(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Full_path));

WebBrowser wb1 = new WebBrowser();
wb1.Navigate(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Full_path, 
Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)));
```

In both cases it issues - "the Value does not fall within the valid range".
Without string encoding-write-the wrong path.

The Full_path string contains the correct path.

Comment: Are you sure the 1251 is the korrect encoding, which you really need?

Comment: This could probably be answered in less than 5 minutes if you documented the value of Full_path.  But you want a manual, that is going to take a while.

Comment: For example: D:\\Полиморфизм.pdf